# Variadic templates with forward reference and operator +=

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, sfinae, forward-reference

I have function which should taken several parameters and after add all parameters to `*this`, `operator+=` is overloaded and work for one parameter. Function look like

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct are_equal :
    std::is_same<typename std::decay<T>::type, U>::type
{};

template<typename T>
template<typename... U>
std::enable_if_t<are_equal<U ..., Object<T>>::value>
Object<T>::addd(U &&... u)
{
//  *this += std::forward<U>(u)...;
}
```

Probably i have two problems. 
1. I think that i should change part of my code with `type_traits`, but my experiments don't give correctly result.
Error with comments line (where is `operator +=`)

> C2893 Failed to specialize function template 'enable_if<_Test,_Ty>::type Object::addd(U &&...)'
>   C2672 'Object::addd': no matching overloaded function found

2. Problem with dictionary(?) in comment line:

   ```
   *this += std::forward<U>(u)...;
   ```

Error:

> C2143  syntax error: missing ';' before '...'
>
> C2059 syntax error: '...'
>
> C3520  'u': parameter pack must be expanded in this context

`Operator+=` work fine for one element (I'm sure).

Comment: Can you give a [mcve]?

Comment: What would you want the pack expansion `std::forward<U>(u)...` to produce? If there is only one parameter, it’s obvious, but what should it be for more than one parameter? Do you perhaps want [C++ 17 fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold)?

Comment: @DanielH i look solution in c++14. I want add all elements from pack to `this`

Answer (score 4):

I assume you want that pack expansion to produce something like this:

```
*this += std::forward<U>(u_1),
*this += std::forward<U>(u_2),
// ...
*this += std::forward<U>(u_n);
```

---

The reason why `*this += std::forward<U>(u)...;` doesn't work is that, roughly speaking, commas produced by a pack expansion <sub>(but not by a fold expression, see below)</sub> can't be used as **operators**.

The classical pre-C++17 workaround is to use a dummy array:

```
using dummy_array = int[];
dummy_array{(*this += std::forward<U>(u), 0)..., 0};
```

Note that commas produced by this expansion aren't used as operators (but rather as separators of element initializers), thus the above restriction isn't applied.

The first `, 0` in the above snippet lets us ignore the return type of `*this += blah`.
The second `, 0` is used to support empty parameter packs (otherwise there would be an attempt to create an empty array, which is not allowed).

The type alias is necessary because the compiler wouldn't let you use `int[]{blah, blah}` directly.

As an alternative to `using`, you could use something like

```
std::enable_if_t<1, int[]>{(std::cout << p, 0)..., 0};
```

---

Another option would be to create an actual array instead of temporary one:

```
int dummy_array[]{(std::cout << p, 0)..., 0};
(void)dummy_array;
```

But I don't like this one too much.

---

#### If you have C++17, you should use [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) instead:

```
((*this += std::forward<U>(u)), ...);
```

Comment: Another solution is to not use pack expansion at all and to instead use recursion, templating on `U` and `URest`, and declaring the function with `addd(U&& u, URest&& rest)`,  recursing on `std::forward<URest>(rest)...`, and adding an empty do-nothing base case.

Comment: @DanielH: You proposal  creates more instantiations, and can thus be slower to compile.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but it’s arguably more readable (and it works if `operator,` is overloaded, but almost nobody does that, for good reason).

Comment: `(f(us), void(), 0)...` handles the evil `operator ,`. Readability is indeed disputable, but C++17 one seems clean and pre-C++17 is similar (but with more boiler plate :-/ ). The recursive one is completely different than C++17.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the following:

```
template <bool ... Bs> struct bools {};

template <bool ... Bs>
using all_of = std::is_same<bools<true, Bs...>, bools<Bs..., true>>;

template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
using are_equal = all_of<std::is_same<T, Ts>::value...>;

template<typename T>
template<typename... Us>
std::enable_if_t<are_equal<T, std::decay_t<Us>...>::value>
Object<T>::add(Us&&... u)
{
    const int dummy[] = {0, ((*this += std::forward<Us>(u)), 0)...};
    static_cast<void>(dummy);
}
```

Comment: thanks, function work, but withour SFINAE, maybe problem is more complex